# Transcendental Numbers and their extension fields

Tags: number-theory, galois-theory

I am doing an intro research project on closure properties of algebraic numbers. I don't have a strong grasp of Galois theory. I wanted to understand the implication of this question and whether it was worth exploring

Can a a collection of mathematical objects which is not algebraic over a field be algebraic over a field extension?
if it is worth exploring can I maybe get an example of when this is possible?

Comment: I think $\sqrt{\pi}$ is algebraic over $\mathbb{R}(\pi)$ but not over $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @EthanBolker $\sqrt\pi\in \Bbb R$, so clearly $\sqrt\pi$ is algebraic over $\Bbb R$.

Comment: @Arthur Of course. I should have said $\mathbb{Q}$ as in your answer.

Answer (score 3):

$\pi$ is not algebraic over $\Bbb Q$. But after extending $\Bbb Q$ to $\Bbb Q(\pi)$, suddenly $\pi$ becomes algebraic (it's even contained in the field itself). As a second example, $\sqrt \pi$ is an element which becomes algebraic without becoming an element of the field.

However, if $K/\Bbb Q$ is an *algebraic* field extension then there is no way $\pi$ can be algebraic over $K$. That's because if $f(\pi) = 0$ for some polynomial with coefficients in $K$, one can use the fact that $K$ is algebraic to find a polynomial $g(x)$ with coefficients in $\Bbb Q$ such that $g(\pi) = 0$.

So, performing an algebraic field extension cannot change which elements are algebraic and which are transcendental, but a transcendental field extension can.

Comment: can you suggest me theorem related to this idea?

Comment: @JoshiMaitreyee This _is_ a theorem. Although I haven't supplied a proof, and most books will probably use a more rigorous language to describe the result. It ought to be mentioned in any book that covers field extensions, allthough I don't think it has a name, other than something like "Theorem 10.16", or "Proposition 5.3".